# If two grids are bound to same data source. Will it fetch data once or twice for both grids?

Tags: radgrid, sqldatasource

I have two Grids on the same page and if i associate them with same datasource. Will it fetch data from DB twice or once and populate both grids. In ASP.Net 4.0 using sql datasource and radGrid from Telerik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will fetch data from DB twice.

Answer (score 0):

It will go to the DB twice, as the grid controls are rendered one after the other when the page is being built before being sent from the server to the client.